# Pseudoinverse of a $2 \times 3$ matrix

Tags: matrices, pseudoinverse

I have a matrix from which I have to find the pseudoinverse, but none of the methods that I found gave me the correct answer (one that Wolfram Alpha gave me).

The matrix is:

$$ \pmatrix{0 & 1 & 0\cr1 & 0 & 0\cr} $$

I would be really thankful if someone could help me :)

Comment: Do you specifically mean the Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse?

Comment: Are the vectors rows or columns?

Comment: I tried to do the Moore-Penrose but it didn't work, or I did something very stupid. They are rows (it's how you put it in wolfram)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your matrix $A = \pmatrix{0 & 1 & 0\cr1 & 0 & 0\cr}$ is almost in the form of the singular-values matrix already, you just have to interchange the rows.  So
$A = U \Sigma V^T$ where 
$$ U = \pmatrix{0 & 1\cr 1 & 0\cr}, \ \Sigma = \pmatrix{1 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 1 & 0\cr}, \ V = \pmatrix{1 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 1 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 1\cr}$$
Then $\Sigma^+ = \Sigma^T$, and the pseudo-inverse is 
$A^+ = V \Sigma^+ U^T$.

Comment: Sorry to bother you with question, but do you mean with  $\Sigma^+ = \Sigma^T$, to take the transpose of $\Sigma$? Then it would make sence that $A^+ = A^T$?

Comment: Yes, the transpose.

Comment: I totally forgot to thank you! Thank you so so much :)